# Downloader downloads high quality video but muted

Tags: node.js, next.js, ffmpeg, socket.io, ytdl

I have created a next.js video downloader and I want to download videos of the highest quality. When I trigger the download I only get a muted mp4 file (in high quality) and a muted mp3 file. Here is the api file. How could I download the video, the audio and then merge them with ffmpeg correctly?

```
import ytdl from "ytdl-core";
import fs from "fs";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Socket is already running");
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  console.log("Socket is initializing");
  const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
  res.socket.server.io = io;

  io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id, "socketID");

    const sendError = async (msg) => {
      socket.emit("showError", msg);
    };

    const sendProgress = async (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      socket.emit("showProgress", msg);
    };

    const sendComplete = async (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      socket.emit("showComplete", msg);
    };

    const downloadVideo = async (url) => {
      try {
        const videoInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
        const outputPath = path.join(
          process.cwd(),
          "mp4s",
          `${videoInfo.videoDetails.title}.mp4`
        );
        const audioPath = path.join(
          process.cwd(),
          "mp4s",
          `${videoInfo.videoDetails.title}.mp3`
        );

        const videoFormat = ytdl.chooseFormat(videoInfo.formats, {
          quality: "highestvideo",
          filter: "videoonly",
        });
        const audioFormat = ytdl.chooseFormat(videoInfo.formats, {
          quality: "highestaudio",
          filter: "audioonly",
        });
        const videoStream = ytdl(url, { quality: videoFormat.itag });
        const audioStream = ytdl(url, { quality: audioFormat.itag });

        const videoOutput = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
        const audioOutput = fs.createWriteStream(audioPath);

        audioStream.pipe(audioOutput);
        videoStream.pipe(videoOutput);

        let downloadedBytes = 0;
        let totalBytes =
          videoFormat.contentLength || videoInfo.length_seconds * 1000000;

        videoOutput.on("data", (chunk) => {
          downloadedBytes += chunk.length;
          const progress = Math.round((downloadedBytes / totalBytes) * 100);
          sendProgress({ progress });
        });

        videoOutput.on("error", (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          sendError({
            status: "error",
            message: "An error occurred while writing the video file",
          });
        });

        audioOutput.on("error", (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          sendError({
            status: "error",
            message: "An error occurred while writing the audio file",
          });
        });

        videoOutput.on("finish", () => {
          audioOutput.on("finish", () => {
            if (fs.existsSync(outputPath) && fs.existsSync(audioPath)) {
              const outputFile = path.join(
                process.cwd(),
                "mp4s",
                `${videoInfo.videoDetails.title}-with-audio.mp4`
              );
              const command = ffmpeg()
                .input(outputPath)
                .input(audioPath)
                .outputOptions("-c:v copy")
                .outputOptions("-c:a aac")
                .outputOptions("-b:a 192k")
                .outputOptions("-strict -2")
                .output(outputFile)
                .on("end", () => {
                  fs.unlink(outputPath, () => {});
                  fs.unlink(audioPath, () => {});
                  sendComplete({
                    status: "success",
                  });
                })
                .on("error", (err) => {
                  console.error("ffmpeg error:", err.message);
                  sendError({
                    status: "error",
                    message:
                      "An error occurred while processing the audio and video files",
                  });
                });
              command.run();
            } else {
              console.error("Output or audio file not found");
              sendError({
                status: "error",
                message: "Output or audio file not found",
              });
            }
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        sendError({
          status: "error",
          message: "An error occurred while downloading the video",
        });
      }
    };
    socket.on("downloadVideo", downloadVideo);
  });
  res.end();
}
```

I am also using socket.io to show the progress in the frontend, but for some reason I don't get the progress correctly. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not a `ytdl` issue; high bitrates are always without audio, so you must download audio and video separately. Here is a [detailed how-to](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/ffmpeg.js), for properly merge two separate streams with `ffmpeg`
This involves some knowledge of `ffmpeg` with multiple input pipes.